# Neglecting the usage of Jetpack Compose Effect Handlers: Possible Consequences?

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, android-jetpack-compose

Currently reading about Jetpack Compose Side Effects & Effect Handlers: [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

What doesn't become clear to me: What happens, when I **don't** use the described Effect Handlers (Launched Effect, DisposableEffect, etc.)?

**What consequences can result from neglecting the usage of Effect Handlers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one has answered yet, I want to share my thoughts on this.

> What consequences can result from neglecting the usage of Effect Handlers?

If you don't want to use `LaunchedEffect` or `DisposableEffect`, you will either have to write a lot of code yourself or you will not be able to implement some use cases.

Some use cases that are easily covered with the built in effect handlers are listed below:

- Execute some suspend function when the Composable initially enters the screen
- Execute some function when the Composable leaves the screen
- Execute some code whenever the value of a parameter has changed

If you are not quite familiar with Compose yet, it might be unclear why you would need these. But while implementing some use cases, there will be the point when you will need them.

See this simple example: 
 You want to trigger a network function as soon as the Composable is displayed. The first approach I would have written is as follows:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(networkViewModel: NetworkViewModel, inputParam1: String, inputParam2: Int) {
    //...
    myData = networkViewModel.loadData()
}
```

But now, whenever `inputParam1` or `inputParam2` change, a recomposition happens, and the `loadData` function will be called again.  We can easily solve this by using a `LaunchedEffect`:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(networkViewModel: NetworkViewModel, inputParam1: String, inputParam2: Int) {
    //...
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        myData = networkViewModel.loadData()
    }
}
```

That way, the function is only called once, and we could also easily make `loadData` a suspend function, as `LaunchedEffect` executes the contained code in a Coroutine.